# Issue in reading repeated fields from protocol buffers in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

org.proto

```
message Optimize {
    required int element_size = 1;
    required string element_name = 2;
}

message nodes {
    repeated Optimize = 1;
}
```

Have this decoding function:

```
DecodeNodeMsg(char *msg, int size)
{

    Org::nodes node;
    int element_size;
    string element_name;
    int NumofElem = 0;

    node.ParseFromArray((void *)msg, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Optimize().size(); i++)
    {
        element_size = nodes.Optimize(i).element_size();
        element_name = nodes.Optimize(i).element_name();
        cout << "size" << element_size << endl;
        cout << "name" << element_name << endl;
        NumofElem++;
    }
    cout << "number of" << NumofElem << endl;
}
```

I am encoding a nodes message with three Optimize messages in it. and calling this decode function. Encoding part is an old code which is working fine from long time. So i dont suspect the encoding function.

In the decode function, I see that the NumofElem is correctly printed as three. However, i see that both element_size & element_name are just garbage. Integer has some junk value and string has a binary data.

I am having this issue only if this repeated fields. If fields are required/optional fields, then i dont have this issue.

Could some one has similar issue... ? if so any clues on how to fix this ?

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Can you please provide code that actually compiles and demonstrates the bug?  The code you have now does not compile -- at least, the `.proto` syntax is not valid and I have doubts about the C++ on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are actually decoding a message. I see you creating a new node object, but then calling Org::nodes() which looks wrong. I think you need to access the Optimize elements like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < node->optimize_size(); i++)
{
    element_size = node->optimize(i).element_size();
    element_name = node->optimize(i).element_name();
    cout << "size" << element_size << endl;
    cout << "name" << element_name << endl;
    NumofElem++;
}
```

But again I think your nodes object needs to be decoded from something. The mutable methods allow you to set data. There's also the ParseFrom methods. Also in my proto files I number the elements in a message. See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

```
 message nodes {
   repeated Optimize = 1;
 }
```

Comment: all three you mentioned are typing mistakes in the question. I have a ParsingFromArray function, nodes is a local variable, so nodes.optimize() is fine, and also i had the numbers for each field in the message. Have updated the question accordingly. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

The function deserializes the buffer into the local variable **node**, but the loop references **nodes**. I'd also validate the return value from ParseFromArray.